# PyMC3 Chain failed when modeling a censored regression

Tags: pymc3

I am trying to model a censored regression based on [this](https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/v3/pymc-examples/examples/generalized_linear_models/GLM-truncated-censored-regression.html) example in PyMC3.
The difference from the example is that my data is only right censored, but apart from that not much difference. I have tried it on some mock data and everything works fine, but when I try to use my real data things starts to go wrong and I get a `RuntimeError: Chain 1 failed.` with a `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide` error and `ValueError: Mass matrix contains zeros on the diagonal.  The derivative of RV 'intercept'.ravel()[0] is zero.` when launching the `pm.sample()` command.
Here is my code:

```
def bayesian_censored_regression(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series, censoring_flag: pd.Series):
    """
    Bayesian censored regression using PyMC3
    """

    x_rc = x[censoring_flag]
    y_rc = y[censoring_flag]

    uncensored = np.logical_not(censoring_flag)
    x = x[uncensored]
    y = y[uncensored]

    sigma_prior = np.std(y)

    with pm.Model() as model:
        slope = pm.Normal("slope", mu=0, sigma=1)
        intercept = pm.Normal("intercept", mu=0, sigma=1)
        σ = pm.HalfNormal("σ", sd=sigma_prior)
        y_likelihood = pm.Normal("y_likelihood", mu=slope * x + intercept, sigma=σ, observed=y)
        right_censored = pm.Potential(
            "right_censored", normal_lccdf(slope * x_rc + intercept, σ, y_rc)
        )

    return model

x = df.var1.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df.var2.values.reshape(-1, 1)
censoring_flag = df.censored.values.reshape(-1, 1)

censored_model = bayesian_censored_regression(x, y, censoring_flag)

with censored_model:
    censored_fit = pm.sample(return_inferencedata=True, draws=10000)
```

As extra info `np.mean(x), np.std(x)` is `(2613.754382911023, 2010.0931627621942)`
and `np.mean(y), np.std(y)` is `(71.57414301625279, 69.44685037573566)`.

How can I debug this error? how can i fix it?
The data can be downloaded from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qZuJ9Yp30olk4RlqjiTPvG0W0ZsaPk9w/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: It could be that the issue is because the two variables do not have a relationship between them. I get the same error if i create a fake `y` variable like: `y = abs(np.random.normal(a_mean, a_std, len(x)))`